# Binding BooleanToVisibilityConverter to a Control in a TreeView HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I have a TreeView object bound to a DataSet.  Inside of the TreeView.ItemTemplate, I am using a HierarchicalDataTemplate containing the controls that I am rendering.

**Does anyone know how to change the Visibility property of a control inside of a HierarchicalDataTemplate?** I have tried using the BooleanToVisibilityConverter from the .NET framework, but cannot get the binding to work properly.

The boolean variable in my ViewModel named "*moveButtonVisibility*" is bound to the Visibility property of the button in my XAML. The BooleanToVisibilityConverter then attempts to convert the corresponding boolean value (true/false) to a Visibility value (visible/hidden). "*moveButtonVisibility*" is not part of the TreeView's ItemSource.

A stripped down version of my code is shown below. I have removed all of the code in my XAML except for the Button control *"MoveHereButton"* that I want to change the visibility property on:

**VIEWMODEL (C#):**

```
private bool _moveButtonVisibility;
public bool moveButtonVisibility
{
    get { return _moveButtonVisibility; }
    set
    {
        _moveButtonVisibility = value;
        RaiseChange("moveButtonVisibility");
    }
}
```

**VIEW (XAML):**

```
<Page>
     <Page.Resources>
         <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter"/>
     </Page.Resources>
     <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="treeView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=rsParentChild}"  Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" >
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
               <Style>
                  <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
               </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                 <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=rsParentChild, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <Grid Focusable="False" Margin="5,10,5,10">
                           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                             <Button Name="MoveHereButton" Content="Move Here" Visibility="{Binding DataContext.moveButtonVisibility, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}" Click="MoveHereButton_Click" />
                        </Grid>
                 </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
             </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: *Does anyone know how to change the Visibility property of a control inside of a HierarchicalDataTemplate?*... yes... you do it the same way as you would to any other control. Check your `Binding` by adding a `TextBlock` like this: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.moveButtonVisibility} />`.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be that straight forward. I get the following error: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:                       'moveButtonVisibility' property not found on 'object' ''DataView' (HashCode=59215815)'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.moveButtonVisibility; DataItem='TreeView' (Name='treeView1'); target element is 'Button' (Name='MoveHereButton'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')

Comment: It is *exactly* that straight forward. You clearly just had a `Binding` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked:

```
<Button Name="MoveHereButton"  
        Content="Move Here" 
        Visibility="{Binding DataContext.moveButtonVisibility, 
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Page}},
                      Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}" 
        Click="MoveHereButton_Click" />
```

The key was to add:

```
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Page}}
```

inside of the `Visibility` binding to force the control to use the `DataContext` of the `Page`.

Comment: If you've found the answer, you can mark your own answer as correct one.

Comment: It says that I cannot accept my own answer as being correct until after 2 days time.